# Play framework entry point

Tags: java, playframework, entry-point

When I send a request from my browser to Play! on `localhost:9000`, what object/method in `PlayFramework` first starts processing my request to the server?

I know `PlayFramework` uses `netty` framework to work with requests. So maybe some netty method starts the execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
play.server.Server.main(...)
  new Server(...)
    bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(new HttpServerPipelineFactory());
      pipeline.addLast("handler", playHandler); [PlayHandler instance is injected to 'netty' factory ]
        messageReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) of PlayHandler will be called-back from netty when a new http message received.
```